# How to redistribute values of a raster according to a gaussian distribution

Tags: raster, r, filter

I have a matrix of dimension 10 x 10, with each cell value equal to 100.

```
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

And I would like to create a new matrix in which these values are distributed according to a gaussian distribution with values higher than 100 in the middle of the matrix and values lower than 100 going towards the borders of the matrix.

However, I want the total sum of values to be the same in the two matrices (therefore 10.000).

Do you have any suggestion on how I could do it in R?

Comment: I know nothing of R, but what you are looking for is called a 2D gaussian kernel (might help you to find an answer). Also, your question is probably off-topic for GIS StackExchange.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the question might look a bit off-topic for GIS StackExchange. However, I'm working with raster data, that's why I asked here.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "distributed according to a Gaussian distribution"? Two quite different interpretations are (1) each cell value is drawn independently from a Gaussian distribution but the means of those distributions are higher near the middle of the raster; and (2) the raster values should be proportional to a (2D) Gaussian (density) function.  The latter is related to the "Gaussian kernel" (cc @ArMoraer) whereas the former might be what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be clear on exactly what you are after here. It is easy to generate a random raster or matrix, following a Gaussian distribution. However, it is quite different to create a 2D Gaussian distribution following z[x,y].

Here is a general methodology to approximate what you are after. You can fool around with scaling the resulting matrix however you want.

Create 10x10 matrix of uniform values

```
( m <- matrix(100,nrow=10,ncol=10) )
```

Create Gaussian distributed matrix with a sd = 1.5

```
library(spatialEco)
( gm <- spatialEco::gaussian.kernel(sigma=1.5, n=10) )
```

Multiply matrices, this step is somewhat meaningless but, demonstrates weighting an existing matrix with a Gaussian distribution.

```
( wm <- m * gm )
```

plot results

```
persp(x=1:nrow(wm),y=1:ncol(wm),z=wm, col="blue")
```

Here we can look at some different sigmas whose effect are a function of the size of the data.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5))     
  for(s in c(0.5, 2, 4, 6)){ 
    gm <- spatialEco::gaussian.kernel(sigma=s, n=50)        
    persp(x=1:nrow(gm),y=1:ncol(gm),z=gm, col="blue")   
  }
```

[image: various_sigmas]

In a simulation framework, you can start digging a bit deeper and simulating multivariate normal kernels. Bit off topic but, still interesting in the realm of 2D kernel estimates. We often neglect multivariate normal in thinking Gaussian normal.

Define some simulated pairwise data

```
nx <- 20
x <- seq(0,2,length=nx)
X <- expand.grid(x, x)
```

Create squared exponential kernel

```
D <- plgp::distance(X)
Sigma <- exp(-D/1)^2 + diag(sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), nrow(X))
```

Sample from multivariate normal distribution with mean zero and specified sigma and plot the results

```
Y <- MASS::mvrnorm(1,rep(0,dim(Sigma)[1]), Sigma)
  persp(x=x,y=x, z=matrix(Y, ncol=nx,nrow=nx), 
        theta=-30, phi=30, xlab="x1", ylab="x2",  
        zlab="y", col="blue")
```

[image: multivariate_norm]

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, very insightful your example. I have another question strictly related. Do you think would be possible to create an "inverse" of the gaussian kernel. That is, I want to create a matrix with higher values on the borders and less in the center. Shall I use the multivariate normal dist in this case? Shall be a bimodal distribution?